# error after building Linux source code for android

Tags: build-process, android-emulator, makefile, linux-kernel, cross-compiling

I have compiled the Linux kernel source for android. After building the source i got error,

that is, after

```
$ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/path/to/mydroid/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi- make
```

i got:

```
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/linux/compile.h
 Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#1)
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 2283 modules
WARNING: modpost: Found 1 section mismatch(es).
To see full details build your kernel with:
'make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y'
```

so i did the following:

```
root@ubuntu:~/common# make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
```

After even after this i got the same output

```
root@ubuntu:~/common# make
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
  SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-x86
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/linux/compile.h
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#3)
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 2283 modules
WARNING: modpost: Found 1 section mismatch(es).
To see full details build your kernel with:
'make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y'
```

The actual output should be

```
 Kernel: arch/arm/boot/Image is ready
 Kernel: arch/arm/boot/zImage is ready
```

**Also i have executed "make" command many times**, now there is no "image" in the arch/arm/boot/ directory. I tried to run the emulator with the image from arch/x86/boot but that didn't work. It gave me an error.
The actual command is

```
./emulator -avd my_avd -kernel ~/common/arch/arm/boot/zImage -show-kernel -verbose
```

Now, as i don't have any image in /arch/arm/boot  i did:

```
root@ubuntu:~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools# ./emulator -avd avd1.5 -kernel ~/common/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -show-kernel -verbose
```

and i got this error:

```
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: can't connect to ADB server: Connection refused
emulator: ping program: /home/preetam/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ddms
emulator: ping command: /home/preetam/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ddms ping emulator 10.0
Unknown cp14 write op1:6 crn:0 crm:8 op2:6
qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0xff91c756

R00=00000000 R01=000005a1 R02=00000100 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=00010010 R15=ff91c756
PSR=400001f3 -Z-- T svc32
Aborted
root@ubuntu:~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools#
```

I don't understand where i am doing wrong, i have done something stupid, please someone tell how can i solve this.?
thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. It's better to ask such questions under [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/) or another more relevant stackexhange section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running:

```
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/path/to/mydroid/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi- make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y
```

So that make runs using the ARM settings

Also, which kernel version are you compiling? Where did you get this kernel?  Why can't you use a kernel from the Android project directly?

Comment: i got it with this: root@ubuntu:~/common# ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=~/mydroid/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi- make

Comment: please please help help me with this::     http://superuser.com/questions/260417/error-while-loading-new-compiled-linux-kernel-image-into-the-android-emulator1-5

Comment: i have enabled full netfilter support in the compiled kernel. i am not able to load the zImage in the android emulator, please help me with that.

Comment: Best to open a new question for that.  Not sure I'd be much help with that, but there'll be others who might be able to help.  Also, posting error log of boot would help too :)

Comment: it was my mistake, i compiled eclair image and tried to put it in cupcake emulator. Now, i have done the whole building process again, and i successfully can load the image to emulator.  And thanks for helping.